# Recommended compressed air source and location for separate air compression system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, compressed-air, compressors, industrial-engineering

I am investigating what would be the most appropriate compressed air source (fan/blower/compressor) for designing a separate air compressor system.

The information is as follows:

- the compressed air would be supplied to the lens of an industrial sensing instrument, which is mounted onto a pipe leading into a boiler's furnace
- there are 12 instruments on each row and there are four rows in total (first row starts at 20m and there is an increase of 5m per row).

Purpose:

- to provide sufficient pressure in order to prevent accumulation of dust on an instrumentation's lens
- to provide sufficient flow to keep the entire pipe free of contaminants in the first place

Demand requirements:

- flow (800 m<sup>3</sup>/hour) for all 84 instruments (100 m<sup>3</sup>/hour for one row of instruments) (**8.6 m<sup>3</sup>/hour for one instrument)**
- pressure (40 mbar)

I know that the pressure demand is very little, it simply needs to be slightly above the furnace pressure. However, my concern is that the fans we have been using have not been able to provide sufficient pressure. Meanwhile, the flow is quite large.

Therefore, I am contemplating between a blower (more powerful fan) or a compressor (not sure if an air receiver would be necessary).

Which one would be more suitable (for both 100 m<sup>3</sup> per hour and 800 m<sup>3</sup>/hour)?

**What are the pros and cons of either (in terms of cost and space required and efficiency).?**

If a compressor, **which type of compressor** (positive displacement, rotary, reciprocating) would be suggested?

Also, the duty cycle is 100% (all the tube needs to be cleaned at all times). If a compressor is used, is a receiver necessary?

How many instruments could be fed with one compressor?

Comment: That is 220 litres a second... really? are all instruments to be cleaned at the same time or sequentially...

Comment: All instruments should be cleaned at the same time. Yes, 220 liters per second if I had just one blower/compressor to clean all the instruments at once.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: First idea is to use a small compressor to charge a receiver tank and then drive the cleaning system from the tank at suitable intervals...

Comment: The first paragraph after the bullet-points seems to have been cut off.

Comment: @SolarMike What are your reasons for choosing a small compressor over a blower or fan? how far should the receiver tank be placed from the small compressor? are you suggesting just one compressor and a receiver tank for all 84 flame monitors? (there are 4 rows each on different elevations of 2m each).

Comment: @udidosa you need to write a complete question and not drip feed information via comments. I gave you a first idea as was clearly stated... You need to decide what you want or are prepared to use - compressor fan etc maybe maintenance requirements could be a controlling factor for you..

Comment: A second thought is to feed each of the 4 systems sequentially from the tank in turn - reduces the load on the tank, losses etc and may improve cleaning effectiveness.

Comment: @SolarMike my apologies for this. I am afraid I don't understand what you mean by sequentially from the tank in turn. All of the four systems need to be supplied with equal amounts of pressure and flow at all times (when the boiler is in operation)

Comment: @SolarMike I'm afraid a small compressor cannot meet the requirement for high flow rate (around 800 m^3/hour) and so would a large compressor be required?

Comment: You did not read all the info I gave, but as it was an idea you can take it or leave it...

Comment: The pressure is so low that a compressor makes no sense.  A centrifugal fan can easily generate the requred pressure - just give the requirements to a fan supplier and they’ll give you a recommendation.

Comment: @mark the pressure required is very low, correct, but we want to generate high enough pressurized air to completely clean a cylindrical tube with air to prevent dust accumulating on the surface and inside the pipe, so I am not sure if high pressure is required or high flow rate. This is why I am trying to decide between (and evaluate both) compressors and blowers. It seems high pressure blowers are feasible but I'd like to make a proper evaluation so I'm looking for some practical points.

Comment: @SolarMike  "use a small compressor to charge a receiver tank and then drive the cleaning system from the tank at suitable intervals" --> forgive me if I do not understand, but won't the pressurized compressed air lose its 'pressure' if the air directly goes into a receiver tank first?

Comment: Just to be clear - you already have a system with fans, and they are not able to provide 40 mbars?  Did the manufacturer specify 40 mbars, and if not, where did that number come from?   The fans may simply be undersized - do you have fan curves for the existing fans?  Or are the fans providing 40 mbars, but you’re not getting the cleaning you need?  Do you have a simple P&ID of the existing system?

Answer (score 1):

From skimming a (sadly german language) "blower bible", it seems that high pressure radial blowers are mostly used in the pressure range you need. Axial blowers appear to deliver a too low pressure, a compressor is certainly overblown for just 40mbar. However, I would suggest that due to your high volume flows you experience significant pressure losses and that may be why your existing blowers are not up to the task.

I don't understand your requirement to deliver 100 or 800 m³/h. A radial blower is the wrong tool to adjust over such a wide range of flow rates when you need mostly contant pressure, you you'd need to mount several in paralell and switch them on/off as needed.

Comment: I forgot: The time honoured engineers way of solving these question is to talk to a likely supplier. Finding a good fit for a problem is what sales engineers are paif for.

Comment: I will draw a proper P&ID and clarify my situation. Essentially I would just like to know if it is feasibly to have centrifugal blowers or use compressors (with air receivers) instead for this compressed air system. By the way, radial blower (centrifugal fan) IS the existing configuration and it can only produce about 50mbar of static pressure.

Comment: then get different radial blowers. I've seen them for up to 300mbar.